# Cannot log in GitHub into Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, github

While trying to push my git repository in Eclipse into GitHub for the first time I'm asked to insert user and password of my GitHub account but it doesn't work. Eclipse shows me the message "Can't connect to any URI: ... " (where ... is the repository link). How can I solve?
I use Eclipse 2021-06 on a MacBook Air

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38345578/16688813) could help you solve your problem.

Comment: Is it not possible with a https link?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try creating a personal acces token, so you can use it instead of your regular password,  to do this, in github go to settings - developer settings - personal access tokens

Comment: How then can i use the personal access token in Eclipse?

Comment: @Mattyred99 See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802292/6505250